# Yielding on UnityWebRequest's 'Send()' makes two calls instead of just one

Tags: node.js, http, unity-game-engine, yield, coroutine

I have already searched, but maybe just couldn't find the right words.
The point is, I'm doing requests to a nodejs/express through Unity/C# using UnityWebRequest on a Coroutine and it always send two requests as the server always print 'request received' twice.

```
//UNITY C# REQUEST
IEnumerator RequestRoutine () {
    using ( UnityWebRequest req = UnityWebRequest.Get ( "http://localhost:8080/blablabla" ) ) {
        yield return req.Send ();

        yield return req.isDone;
        Debug.Log ( "is done" );
    }
}

//NODE.JS server
app.get('/blablabla', (req, res) => {
    console.log('request received')
    res.end()
})
```

Comment: I'll admit that I'm rather weak in the coroutine knowledge, but you *do* have two `yield`s in your function. I don't think you need that second one (`yield return req.isDone`). [The Manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UnityWebRequest-CreatingDownloadHandlers.html) also only refers to the `req.Send()` yield.

Comment: Where is the `RequestRoutine()` call site in your code?  Is it part of a script that's attached to more than 1 object. (IE do you see more than 1 `is done` in the Unity log?)  `yield return req.isDone` shouldn't be an issue, it just means the coroutine needs an additional frame before printing `is done`.

Comment: @Draco18s The two yield calls are not an issue (did the same with just the first one). You are right, the docs does refers to 'yield req.Send()', but this can be an issue one the nodejs/express maybe, because I have already done request to other kind of servers and never had this issue.

Comment: @Jerdak Sorry, I have posted just the code that I thought would be necessary. The call happens as StartCoroutine(RequestRoutine()) in just one object and it does only once as I have already printed a message when doing this call.

Comment: I meet same problem. Is there any new information about this issue?